# Unsuccessfull redirecting on 'YOURLS' url shortener

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url, yourls

so I just implemented the [YOURLS](http://yourls.org) script successfully, or so I thought.

It generates the shortened URL succesfully and adds it too the [YOURLS](http://yourls.org) url ID table, but when I try and navigate to the website, via using the new shortened url. I always get the same error message in the browser.

```
Not Found

The requested URL /4 was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.3 (Unix) Server at scof.me Port 80
```

Most appreciated if you could help!

Comment: Provide the name of the script getting called, your .htaccess file (in case you use mod_rewrite) and the overall folder structure of your server.

Comment: Is .htaccess is provided in the latest release of Yourls? I can't find it?

Comment: Don't know. I just asked to provide more details. You question is far too short

Comment: Looking at the code, Yourls seems to be supposed to create a .htaccess file at install time

Comment: can't find it anywhere in the file manager. Is there source code/script for the .htaccess file available for download?

Answer (score 2):

YOURLS has information on creating the .htaccess file manually on [this page.](http://code.google.com/p/yourls/source/search?q=htaccess&origq=htaccess&btnG=Search%20Trunk)

For a root install, the file has to look like this:

> **Case: YOURLS installed on root**
>
> If YOURLS root URL is http://www.example.com/, the .htaccess file in the root directory must be like:
>
> ```
> # BEGIN YOURLS
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /yourls-loader.php [L]
> </IfModule>
> # END YOURLS
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Pekka, I've created the .htaccess and uploaded it to the file manager server, but still doesn't work :S

Comment: @AlexDuncan did you get anywhere with this?  I can't install it either, same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on amazon aws ubuntu 12 and solved here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/48362/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-in-apache

> "If you plan on using mod_rewrite in .htaccess files, you also need to
>   enable the use of .htaccess files by changing AllowOverride None to
>   AllowOverride FileInfo. For the default website, edit
>   /etc/apache2/sites-available/default:"

And yes I plan on using mod_rewrite in .htacess then..

Then you have to restart apache.